# Retrieving only name of user who owns folder

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I'm making a bash script that has to create subfolders and expand files into a mounted folder. My Problem is that I can't create subfolders as ROOT, i need to the commands in my script as:

```
su - UnknownUser -c "mkdir MAKEDir"
```

So my question is, how can I only retrieve the user name when doing commands like

```
ls -l
```

Thanks for any input!

Comment: Not very sure but is the ls -ld or may be this ls -l /path/to/file?

Comment: ls -ld gives the current directory owner, it still gives me stuff I don't want like ther read permissions and timestamps

Comment: Your statement above sounds like 2 requests. Can't create directory and listing just user name from the ls command. Do you just want to show only the current directory owner?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use stat -c with a format of %U for the textual name of the owner, or %u for the uid of the owner (or %G/%g for group)

```
stat -c %U <filename>
```

Comment: This works for GNU `stat`; other implementations may use different options or formats.

Answer (score 4):

The `stat` command varies greatly by implementation, but the following will work

```
# GNU stat
# -c may be used in place of --format
$ stat --format %U file.ext

# BSD (Mac OS X, anyway) stat
$ stat -f %Su file.ext
```

Answer (score 0):

use awk:

for the user of file foo: 
ls -l foo | awk '{print  $3}'

or, for user and filename together: 
ls -l | awk '{print  $3, $9 }'

Answer (score 0):

If "parent" is the parent directory...

```
user=$(ls -ld ${parent} | awk '{print $3}')
sudo -u $user mkdir ${parent}/child1
sudo -u $user mkdir ${parent}/child2
sudo -u $user mkdir ${parent}/child1/grandchild1
sudo -u $user mkdir ${parent}/child1/grandchild2
```